# how to share a .mp3 file by UIActivityViewController with Swift?

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, uiactivityviewcontroller

In my app I download a music file with extension .mp3 and save it to DocumentDirectory. After I retrieve the url and create a NSData variable, share it on Telegram by UIActivityViewController. The file appeared on telegram has no extension and doesn't play. Its name is "file". I want the music appears like "test.mp3" on Telegram. Here is my code:

```
var paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(.DocumentDirectory, .UserDomainMask, true)[0].stringByAppendingString("/test.mp3")                    

let soundData=NSData(contentsOfFile: paths)

let r = NSURL(fileURLWithPath: paths)

let activityViewController = UIActivityViewController(activityItems: [r] , applicationActivities: nil)
```

Answer (score 0):

I've never used the Telegram API before, but what you would need to do is create a custom `UIActivity` that would store the information to retrieve the song from your local, and with this you can react to the selection of your `UIActivity` and call the Telegram API with the song data.

**1)** Create a custom activity by subclassing `UIActivity`.

```
class YourCustomActivity: UIActivity {

    var title: String!
    var image: UIImage?
    var type:UIActivityType!
    var path: String!


    init(title: String, image: UIImage?, path: String) {
        super.init()
        self.path = path
        self.image = image
        self.title = title
        type = UIActivityType(rawValue: title)
    }

    override var activityType: UIActivityType {
        return self.type
    }

    override var activityTitle: String {
        return self.title
    }

    override var activityImage: UIImage? {
        return self.image
    }

    var activityCategory: UIActivityCategory {
        return .share
    }

    override func canPerform(withActivityItems activityItems: [Any]) -> Bool {
        return true
    }

    override func prepare(withActivityItems activityItems: [Any]) {

    }

    override func perform() {

    }

}
```

---

**2)** Create a class method that will instantiate your Telegram `UIActivity`.

```
class func getTelegramActivitiesFor(path: String) -> [YourCustomActivity] {
    // You have to supply your own "Telegram_Logo"
    return [YourCustomActivity(title: "Telegram", image: UIImage.init(named: "Telegram_Logo", in: Bundle.main, compatibleWith: nil), path: path)]
}
```

---

**3)** Instantiate your `UIActivityController` with your Telegram activity.

```
let yourSongPath = "" // Get path to your song in documents

let activities = YourCustomActivity.getTelegramActivitiesFor(path: yourSongPath)

let activityVC = UIActivityViewController(activityItems: activityImages, applicationActivities: activities)
activityVC.modalPresentationStyle = .popover
activityVC.popoverPresentationController?.barButtonItem = actionButton
present(activityVC, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

---

**4)** When `YourCustomActivity` is selected it will execute its `perform()` method. Here is where you will want to grab the data for your song's path and make the call to send it to [Telegram](https://core.telegram.org/api).

```
override func perform() {
    do {

        let songData = try Data(contentsOf: self.path)

        // Make the API call to Telegram with your song's data...

    }
    catch {
        print("UNABLE TO RETRIEVE SONG")
    }
}
```